# Php extracting a zip, strange behaviour

Tags: php, function, zip, extract

so i'm currently facing a strange behaviour in php, it might be something fairly easy to solve but I have been searching and looking my code for an 1h or 2, and i'm still stuck a the same place. Thanks for your help in advance.

So here is my problem

So I have this function

```
function extractZip($pathToZip, $pathToExtract){
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($pathToZip) === true){
        $zip->extractTo($pathToExtract);
        $zip->close();
    }
    unlink($pathToZip);
}
```

And I use it with a zip built like this

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/files
```

The problem is when I extract it as so
    extractZip("path/to/zip.zip", "path/to/extract");

the structure becomes weird

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/files -> this is fine
/folder2/folder3 -> this is weird because it recreates all the folders
and they are empty, but I don't want those useless folder!
```

Thank you and if something is not clear just ask questions

Comment: have you first tried uploading zip file and then extract? And the problem is, in your case `folder1` is missing.. is it?

Comment: yes it did not work thx for your help, the weird thing is I already work with the exact same function and nothing like this ever happened :\

Comment: checkout this link. http://bavotasan.com/2010/how-to-upload-zip-file-using-php/

Comment: also can you give the actual values that you are passing to the function?

Comment: yes here they are 
    extractZip("wp-content/mu-plugins.zip", "wp-content/mu-plugins/");

Comment: Thank you, but I found my problem, I just updated my php version to 5.6, so it must have been a bug in the version I was using on my server!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading php to the newest version corrected the problem, (php 5.6)